# How to rmdev a list of hdisk in one shot in AIX

Tags: aix

In AIX I have a long list (more then 30) of hdisks I need to delete them in one shot, what command can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic answer for any command on any Unix-like OS:

```
while read -r item; do
    rmdev "$item"
done < itemlist.txt
```

Or:

```
xargs -d'\n' -n1 rmdev < itemlist.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for hdisk in $(cat hdisk.txt);
do;
   rmdev -Rl $hdisk;
done
```

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on the answer to explain how it works? It's not terribly difficult to understand, but not everyone is familiar with the syntax of AIX terminal commands. Explaining how it works will make the answer better for future visitors to the site.