# Removing multiple hdisk from smitty->devices ->fixed disk-> remove

Tags: aix

[Original Code that I saw](https://superuser.com/questions/346088/how-to-rmdev-a-list-of-hdisk-in-one-shot-in-aix/1118889#1118889)

I want to do the same thing but need to make sure i dont delete hdisk0 since this is my OS.

[photo of drives being deleted.](https://gyazo.com/c79500a393cc2cb0630766417ff68140)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the hdisk0 is in use the system wont delete it. it will error out

"smitty->devices ->fixed disk-> remove" don't have the option to select multiple. if you want to remove multiple disks use the following for loop.

it will remove all disks but hdisk0.

```
for i in `lspv |grep -v hdisk0|awk '{print $1}'`;do rmdev -dl $i; done
```

if you want to remove all defined disk:

```
for i in `lsdev -Cc disk |grep Defined|awk '{print $1}'`; do rmdev -dl $i; done
```

the -d in rmdev command removes the device definition.

Comment: so on the command line am i running that entire line?? for i in lspv |grep -v hdisk0|awk '{print $1}'; do rmdev-dl $i; done ???

Comment: Yes. just fixed the formatting

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d6137e96f291a3a3d2dea218826cda08 is the loop an actual value of how many drives i have in there??

Comment: Yes. the lspv command will list all disks. and the grep -v will exclude hdisk0.

Comment: Are you trying to remove just the defined disks?

Comment: Yeah so i want to do grep Defined. Im removing all the defined formats. Since these are all created after I format drives. And when Im doing up to 40 at a time its a pain to have to remove each one individually.

Comment: then use the second for loop

Comment: https://gyazo.com/86b044f0e4ab7ce2d8a989bc46096672

Comment: Should i do -Cc fixed disk??

Comment: yes the second for loop not the first one

Comment: I took a photo. It gave me an error of rmdev: not a recognized flag: C and rmdev: '}' not found

Comment: Please copy the second for loop and paste that in your shell. you replaced the ticks with single quote